# One’s love confession vs. One’s confession of love

Tags: grammar, attributive-nouns

The following is an extract taken from an Italian student's piece of English homework *before* I corrected it.

> Also Mr Amos’s girlfriend, Sabina, arrives to the restaurant, and **she
>   assisted to David’s** [Mr Amos] **love confession to Anna.** Then the waiter began
>   singing his love to Anna. A fight broke out and Anna decided to leave
>   the restaurant.

What's bothering me is the phrase: *... she assisted to David's love confession to Anna*, which I corrected as

> 1) ... she listened as David confessed his love to Anna
>   and *possibly*
>   2) ... she listened to David's confession of love for Anna

But could I have left it as *David's love confession*?

> 3) ... she listened to David's love confession for Anna

The phrase **to confess one's love** is idiomatic and grammatical, but what about "one's love confession"? I can't explain why *love confession* is inappropriate (or ungrammatical).

Google is of no help, and Google Books gives a lot of false positives, which however confirm that *love confession* is at least, an unusual expression.

Examples of ["his love confession"](https://www.google.it/search?q=love%20confession&oq=love%20confession&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22his%20love%20confession%22&start=0) using Google's search engine. These are taken from the first three pages. Although the phrase "his love confession" appears to be common,  it's clear the following are not written by native speakers.

- *A top Japanese star confesses his love for Kara's Nicole? On the recent episode of Japanese music show "Music Station" Nicole and Japanese rock band member from L'Arc~en~Ciel share an incident [where Nicole receives his "love confession."](http://forums.soompi.com/en/discussion/1367783/nicole-receives-a-love-confession-from-top-japanese-star)*
- *He was completely frustrated, this was all Takao's fault with [his stupid love confession.](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9824270/1/Love-Confession)*
- *In a dream, Banri remembers that after [his love confession to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Golden_Time_episodes) Linda, she agreed to tell him her response the following night on the bridge where Banri would have his accident*.
- *Cho kyuhyun loved Seo Joo-hyun so much and started [his own love confession to](http://www.asianfanfics.com/story/view/200203/his-love-confession-two-shot-haefany-kyuhyun-romance-seohyun-seokyu-sulli-twoshot) Seo Joo-hyun*. He started giving lots of presents to Seo Joo-hyun which make Seo Joo-hyun's life miserable.
- *Ji Hyun Woo Shares His Thoughts For First Time After [His Sudden Love Confession](http://www.kpopstarz.com/articles/9042/20120611/ji-hyun-woo-shares-his-thoughts-for-first-time-after-his-sudden-love-confession.htm)*

**Clarification**
The excerpt is from a student's summary of a short American story. The original author does not use the word *confession* or *vow* in any form, shape or size. It is the only the student's attempt (and quite a good one too IMO) to summarise the episode at the restaurant table. My query is not whether there is a better way to rephrase *love confession*, but as to whether it is idiomatic, acceptable and easily understood. I believe it is not idiomatic, but I can't explain why it is not "acceptable".

Comment: Not the DV, but a question - does that statement really help you? I'm curious. Does anyone ever reverse, or make one's down-voter confession as a result? Anyway, I wish I was teaching English in Italy... Maybe it's because they think love confession is ok.

Comment: @medica he's a good kid, does his homework then comes to me. We have a few laughs, but when time's short and/or the grammatical explanation doesn't come immediately to mind, I tell him that we'll talk about it next week.

Comment: Wow, there is a difference in meaning ? I need to think about it now. In grammar, there is no difference between grammar and usage; but in usage there is.

Comment: Re the bounty - I think tchrist's answer did it all. Grammatically all three are fine, but using 'love' as an attributive noun (like an adjective) just sounds weird in 'love confession'. There are the set phrases 'love triangle', 'love bite', 'love child', but 'love confession' sounds like, I don't know, one's love of the universe (?) and not a confession of love of one person for another.

Comment: It is clearly neither a matter of idiomatics nor collocations, but semantics here. The reference is to the noun *confession* with an incidental qualification of *love,* the focus needed to be on the main subject. *Confession of love* would have defeated the purpose by diverting attention toward *love* (with, incidentally, its confession). The wording must have come to the author instinctively from the thought process, not literary technique.

Comment: Perhaps there's a connection to the word "vow(s)" that your Student discovered in his/her examination of the original (Italian?) text that went from "love vow(s)" to "love confession." Personally I see/hear nothing wrong with either "love vow" or even "love confession" in this context (61 years old/native American English speaker to preemptively address any generational concerns deemed relevant). Less idiomatic than "vow/avowal of love" or "confession of love," for sure, perhaps even cleverly so, but certainly not necessarily "wrong," IMwO.

Comment: This piece is not translated from Italian. It is part of a summary of a short American story, the original text does not contain the word "confession" but only Mr. Amos's words of love for Anna. David, his long-time girlfriend, Sabina, and Anna are all sitting at a restaurant table. There is no vow nor promise of eternal love in the light-hearted story.

Comment: @LittleEva There is no translation, it is the student's own words. In Italian the verb "[assistere](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/assistere)" looks very similar to the English *assist*, but the meaning is not exactly the same. Here the student wants to say that Sabina was present (i.e. she listened) when David told Anna he loved her. tchrist's answer explains it better than I do :) The student is doing what many non-native speakers do, he thinks in his mother tongue and then translates it into English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Matters of Love and War

Both your first two versions seem fine, but the third one does not.  As you observe, *confession of love* is the normal collocation, not **love confession*, but it is hard to pin down precisely why that should be so.

It is **not** so much a matter of grammar but rather one of customary couplings of one word to another.  For some combinations, one uses *love* attributively in front of the noun, but for others, one needs the full prepositional version with *love* trailing along afterwards.

After all, one has *love scenes, love stories, love letters, love bites, love songs, love affairs, love interests, love offerings*, and *love potions* — amongst many others.  But one today has only *labo(u)r of love* not **love labo(u)r* (despite Shakespeare’s *Love’s Labour’s Lost*). This is like how one has *affairs of the heart* not **heart affairs*.

Perhaps this is because when *love* is used attributively, it may in at least some cases more strongly attract the “about” or “for” notion than the simpler “of” notion.  A love story is a story **about** love.  A love potion is a potion **for** love, not of it.

But that is not a particularly strong tendency, and in some combinations it does not hold.

Really then, given two nouns *XXX* and *YYY* in English, whether you can (or must) say *the XXX of YYY* or *the YYY XXX* or *YYY’s XXX* often depends on which version people are most accustomed to hearing and seeing. This can change over time, too.

Besides *love*, another word whose combinations are not always predictable is ***war***.  Consider *dogs of war, fog of war, tug of war, prisoners of war, spoils of war, case for war*.  A *war dog* would be something else altogether, as would be a *war case* or a *war tug*, so we do not say those.  With *war fog, war spoils*, and *war prisoners*, we just aren’t used to saying them that way. In particular, *war fog* seems to make no sense at all.

In contrast, we do have *war efforts, war crimes, war reporters, war rooms, war dead,* and of course *war heroes*.  And we have only *crimes of passion*, never **passion crimes*.

I think your *confession of love* is like that: that’s how we’re used to hearing it, so that’s what our ear is expecting.

---

### Translation Hazards for Romance Speakers

I notice that your student is calquing Italian *assistere* in its “attend” or perhaps “join” sense and then dragging along the preposition with it.  Neither works well in today’s English.

I’m presuming the desired sense is that Sabina did not so much aid in the confession but rather attended it — that is, she joined them or simply happened to be present to overhear the confession. (Whether the thought was to listen to or to hear or to overhear, well, that’s something else, more related to intent.)

I’ve often heard this very same calquing of this particular verb into English by native speakers of Romance languages with the same verb, whatever its cognate in their respective Latin-derived language. As you note, it doesn’t really carry that “attend” sense in the English — the English of today, that is.

It is quite true that *assist* could once upon a time do both jobs in English just as it still does in Romance. But these days using it just to mean standing by or being present sounds rather “off” to us.  The OED marks three out of the four such senses of *assist* as obsolete, and the fourth one’s latest citation specifically notes that this is the “French” sense of the verb.

When presenting Shakespeare unedited, this can cause confusion. For example, in *The Tempest*, this line occurs:

> The King, and Prince, at prayers, let’s assist them.

That is not the *assist* that means aid, but rather the now-obsolete one that meant join them or accompany them.  If the word is left unaltered, modern audiences may become confused over its intended sense.

Speaking of dragging the preposition along with it, the choice of *arrive **to***  instead of the normal *arrive **at*** is also unfortunate, and another sure sign that we’re dealing with a Romance speaker with just one preposition *a* for situations where English variously uses *to* or *at*, plus sometimes *in* and in less common cases even *from*.

The Romance learner needs to learn precisely which English preposition  *a* maps to on a case-by-case basis, including those cases where no preposition at all is the best choice.  This is just like how the English learner studying Romance must do the same thing going the other direction, for no overarching rule applies.  Every verb’s “preposition affinities” are strongly idiomatic and vary from one language to the next.

Comment: Thank you. I've read the answer three times now, so rest assured your time was not wasted. As for the *assistere* = "assist" expression, a good alternative I find is  in the verb *witness* as in: "She witnessed his confession".

Comment: An excellent discussion of the issues raised by the OP's question.

Comment: Googling "love confession" returns more results than "confession of love" does, so your claim that the latter is the normal collocation is a bit dubious.

Comment: @Ink Lots of people love confession. Not the same thing. Try any other noun used attributively before *confession*: good luck making it work.

Comment: @tchrist Murder confession.

Comment: @Ink And “*innocence confession’?  I think not. It has to be a “confession of innocence”.

Comment: @tchrist Perhaps because people generally do not confess innocence. Anyway, "confession of innocence" does not sound like a commonly uttered phrase.

Comment: @Ink Neither do they "confess murder", you will note.  But [confessions of innocence](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%22confession+of+innocence%22&tbm=bks&start=10) happen.

Comment: 'Love confession' sounds acceptable to me, as I presume it would with most English speakers, so I'm not sure on what basis you would say it's not.

Comment: @Ink On the basis that it doesn’t sound right either to me or to the OP, both of whom are native speakers.

Comment: Well I am a native speaker as well, and 'love confession' sounds acceptable, as I have heard and spoken the phrase "love confession' with love being used attributively.  Fortunately, English grammar is not dictated.

Comment: Why is that relevant, son?

Comment: @Ink It’s relevant because speech communities are not uncommonly stratified by generation, and she and I belong to the same generation. Do you?

Comment: @Ink would you ever say: "She listened to his love confession"? I don't believe there *is* a reason for it being "wrong", but as tchrist's answer showed,  it's more a question of collocation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA As a matter of brevity, I would.

Comment: @Ink  I believe a native speaker would normally say: *"She listened to his declaration of love"*. That is the most idiomatic expression in my opinion. Brevity was not the issue.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That sounds a bit too literary to me, but to each his own.

Comment: @Ink How ironic! The opposite sounds a bit too illiterate to me!

Comment: As counter-intuitive (and probably non-sensical) as this may sound, I sometimes do not read other answers, especially from "strong-answerers", in order to work the issues out on my own. This answer is one of those, an answer I only just "ingested." It's a good answer, the kernel of which my answer largely echoes ("It is not so much a matter of grammar but rather one of customary couplings..."; "I think your confession of love is like that: that’s how we’re used to hearing it, so that’s what our ear is expecting.").

Comment: In comment, however, you seem to take a more emphatic stance in opposition ("it doesn’t sound right either to me or to the OP") so I was wondering if you would give me a bit of feedback on my answer. I tend to approach English from a poetic sensibility and, for that reason, find phrases like "confession of love" rather tired. I can appreciate the mash-up of unexpected and unusual word combinations as they tend to rouse me from my somnolence. I value your input here, so thanks.

Comment: @Little Eva. With poetic language all bets are off since poets often stretch or break conventions of syntax. The same applies to headlines or titles, as in some of the examples in your answer, which may consist solely of a chain of nouns. The OP’s question, however, is about everyday language, and there are at least four respondents to whom “_David's love confession to Anna_” sounds suspect in such a context.

Answer (score 6):

A confession of love is a confession that one loves. Similarly, a declaration of love is a declaration that one loves, an assertion of love is an assertion that one loves, and evidence of love is evidence that one (or someone) loves.

In each of these cases it sounds odd (at least to me as a native speaker) to speak of a *love confession*, a *love declaration*, a *love assertion* or *love evidence*.

The other examples where *love* is used attributively cannot be expanded into a *that-clause* containing the verb '*to love*'. So a *love story* is not a story that one (necessarily) loves, but a story about love. And a *love child* is not a child that one (necessarily) loves, but a child conceived in love.

If the principle suggested above is correct, then we would expect a preference for post-modification with an *of-phrase* (over the corresponding attributive use) in other noun combinations that can be expanded into a *that-clause*. And this is indeed the case for the following pairs of phrases:

> ?a knowledge denial - a denial of knowledge (a denial that one knew)
> [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20knowledge%20denial%2Ca%20denial%20of%20knowledge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20denial%20of%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0)
>
> ?a help assurance - an assurance of help (an assurance that one will
> help) [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20help%20assurance%2Can%20assurance%20of%20help&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20assurance%20of%20help%3B%2Cc0)

The principle also applies when the *that-clause* contains a copula and the adjectival form of the noun used attributively or in the *of-phrase*:

> ?a guilt confession - a confession of guilt (a confession that one is
> guilty) [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20guilt%20confession%2Ca%20confession%20of%20guilt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20confession%20of%20guilt%3B%2Cc0)
>
> ?an interest admission - an admission of interest (an admission that
> one is interested) [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20interest%20admission%2Can%20admission%20of%20interest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20admission%20of%20interest%3B%2Cc0)
>
> ?an excellence sign - a sign of excellence (a sign that something is
> excellent) [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20excellence%20sign%2Ca%20sign%20of%20excellence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20sign%20of%20excellence%3B%2Cc0)

None of the *Ngrams* for the phrases above yield any results at all for the attributive version.

---

**Addendum**

Having had the time to investigate this issue a little further, I offer this addendum as a brief discussion of the principles governing the premodification of nouns by other nouns. The main source of this additional information is Quirk et al's *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (p1330-1331).

Quirk notes that there is a general tendency in noun phrases such that:

> " ... the premodifying structure has reduced explicitness in relation to
> the postmodifying structure, and if the relationships between the
> nouns become unclear or unpredictable, premodification is
> unacceptable."

According to Quirk, *the Lincoln road* and *this grammar book* are "*fully possible premodification alternatives by prepositional phrase*" to the postmodified *the road to Lincoln* and *this book on grammar*.

But *?fire action* and *?this sentence meaning* "*have an unusual ring*" about them as equivalents of *action in case of fire* and *the meaning of this sentence*. And *?the church house* is not explicit enough to show the relationship *in the house beyond the church*. Finally, **a stream tree* is "*unacceptable*" as an alternative to *a tree by a stream*.

It could be therefore that a *love confession* or a *love declaration* "*have an unusual ring about them*" because the relationship between the nouns is unclear or unpredictable. So a *love confession* could be a confession that one makes while one is in love or a confession about a previous love, as well as a confession that one is in love.

I'm not sure that this is a completely convincing explanation. But Quirk does not provide any criteria by which the lack of clarity or the unpredictability of the relationship between the two nouns could be determined. And I for one do not see any lack of clarity in the questionable phrase *?this sentence meaning*.

Comment: Nor do I find any ambiguity in "*love confession*." Your assertion is well-put, but I find the theory overly deterministic.

Comment: @Little Eva. Well, the assertion is from Quirk, who says: "_if the relationships between the nouns become unclear or unpredictable, premodification is unacceptable_". I hedged my comment on whether this is the reason for _love confession_ having "an unusual ring" with the words "_it could be that .._". I don't know if this is an adequate explanation, but at least it is plausible. And it is certainly the case that _a love confession_ is ambiguous out of context.

Comment: I was referring to your principle primarily which you then associated with Quirk. Virtually any phrase is vulnerable to ambiguity out of context, though, for me, "love confession" is not one of those. I didn't claim the construction was "poetic", only that I have a poet's ear. As to the rest it seems you have either not read my answer or misunderstand it. Please read the dialogue between OP and me in comment below my answer. I enjoyed your answer, Shoe. :-)

Comment: @Little Eva, you have an interesting exchange going with Mary Lou in the comments under your post. I rather suspect that any student who demonstrates the level of sophistication needed to knowingly choose the marked "_love confession_" over the unmarked "_confession of love_" is not a student who is in need of English lessons.

Comment: Yes, and BTW, I thought your principle was probably useful as a general guide. As per my comments, as the third answerer of this OP, my challenge was a tad more difficult than yours, or tchrist's. I had to "stake-out" my own territory in order to provide a relevant answer that was distinguishable from the earlier two, so my options were significantly reduced, *plus*, I had to provide a response I actually could believe in. I took the only path I saw available and I believe I've added positively to the discourse.

Comment: Agreed. I think OP's question is very interesting. It has generated some good quality answers and comments, most certainly including yours!

Answer (score 3):

> The phrase to confess one's love is idiomatic and grammatical, but what about "one's love confession"? I can't explain why love confession is inappropriate (or ungrammatical).

While “love confession” is unusual, in my opinion it is neither *un*idiomatic nor ungrammatical. It sounds, rather, categorical or titular, i.e., a “love letter” as opposed to a “letter of love.” If “love confession,” in comparison with “confession of love,” has a virtue, that virtue lies precisely in its unfamiliarity. Whereas the competing construction, “confession of love,” is so formulaic and commonplace as to be banal.

To me, what would be of primary interest here---after, of course, a determination of grammatical *vs* ungrammatical issue---is whether or not the student’s formulation was knowing and intentional, or whether the end result was merely a fortunate, or unfortunate, accident.

**Sample results of a google search for “love confession” (and these are not false positives):**

> • **15 Great Love Confessions in Film and TV; Movies; Lists** 
>   Feb 14, 2013
>
> And yet, the love confession has become one of pop culture's most popular go-to tropes. [**great love confessions**](http://www.pastemagazine.com/blogs/lists/2013/02/14-great-love-confessions-in-film-and-tv.html)
>
> • **Love Confession---TV Tropes**
>
> The Love Confession trope as used in popular culture. This is when one character makes a declaration of love **to** another. Google, “TV Tropes” [**love confession**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LoveConfession)
>
> • **Love Confessions | Facebook**
>
> Love Confessions. 2048 likes • 16 talking about this. Ever fallen in Love? Confess here how u felt? [**love confession**](https://www.facebook.com/l0ve.c0nfessi0ns)
>
> • **Love Confessions---Amazon.com**
>
> Love Confessions: Activating the Power of the Love of God Through the Spoken Word. [**Love Confessions**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1575627698)
>
> • **Japan's "Love Confessing" Culture---Tofugu**
>
> You may go out with the person a few times or go out on a group date, but your relationship hasn't technically started until this love confession, aka *kokuhaku*, occurs... [**Love Confessing**](http://www.tofugu.com/2013/10/23/japans-love-confessing-culture/)
>
> • **Love Confession on Tumblr**
>
> Find and follow posts tagged ***love confession*** on Tumblr.

**Then, of course, there is:**

> • **Love Confessions---Wikipedia**
>
> Love Confessions is the second studio album by American R&B singer Miki Howard. Released in 1987 under Atlantic Records, the album peaked at No. 145.
>
> • **The Love Connection**
>
> an American television game show (1983–1998), hosted by Chuck Woolery, in which singles attempted to connect with a compatible partner.
>
> • **The Love Boat**
>
> an American television series (1977–1987) set on a cruise ship

Comment: But you do not say:  "**My/your/his** etc. love confession **to**"

Comment: Remove "love" and you have, "Sabina listened to David's [ ] confession to Anna" - nothing wrong with this as far as I can tell. What would sound wrong, to me, would be to say, "Sabina listened to David's [ ] confession **for** Anna". Does the inclusion of "love" make it ungrammatical?

Comment: It's [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22his+love+confession%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) which gives a lot of false positives, Google doesn't see the period. Go and figure... But thank you for the feedback nevertheless :)

Comment: @LittleEva Sometimes removing a single word makes all the difference. The naturalness of "X's confession to" says nothing about the naturalness of "X's love confession to".

Comment: Certainly, @curiousdannii, there are times when exorcizing a word would make all the difference in the world. I was trying to demonstrate that the awkwardness or remarkability of "*love confession*", in the exemplar, is not due to it being ungrammatical but rather to it being unfamiliar in comparison to "*confession of love*". *Sabina listened to David's love confession to Anna* is grammatically acceptable, if idiomatically unusual.

Comment: @LittleEva I didn't say that it was strictly ungrammatical, but it is very unnatural.

Comment: So in short you're saying that that phrase is perfectly fine, and sounds perfectly natural. The Italian student is not writing poetry or lyrics to a song, where originality and quirkiness are more than welcomed, he's writing a summary, and he's learning English. If you were his private teacher, or a state school teacher teaching English, you would say nothing and leave that phrase well alone?

Comment: I seem to have a run afoul of a valued friend. Sorry. I think my answer is as clear as your question. The construction is not ungrammatical; the construction is hardly unheard of, but its frequency of usage pales in comparison with the other. If it has a virtue, that virtue lies solely in its unfamiliarity. The competing construction is standard and unremarkable. To me, what would be *dispositive* (were I the teacher) is whether or not the student’s construction was knowing or a result of ignorance. Try to understand my answer had to be distinguished from Shoe and tchrist's responses. Not easy

Comment: I live in a country where English is not spoken 24 hours a day. Many of my friends and relatives are Italian, the TV is in Italian. I don't have my ear to the ground, there are many new expressions, slang, abbreviations etc. of which I am unfamiliar with. Before telling a student "we do not say this" I have to be sure, because English is continually evolving, then I try to explain why. The student's phrase is comprehensible, but *today*  do native speakers actually say or write it?!  I don't think they do, not spontaneously anyway.

Comment: Some thoughts: the unfamiliar construction would be perfectly understandable and unambiguous (and, delivered in an Italian accent, charming--at least to these American ears). Again, were I the teacher, I would want to know if the student "knew" what they were expressing, and "why" they chose that particular construction over the more standard. If the choice was "informed" it would be fine; if not it qualifies as mistaken. To me, this is the "crux" of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

We can have *confessions of love* and *professions of love* (not to be confused with "the oldest profession").

Common sense informs us that a man stands a better chance of having his love reciprocated when he professes to love a woman than when he confesses to love her.

Sometimes a guy needs a wing-man who *assists with* the profession of love in some manner.

Comment: Good *and* funny. Continuing on your reasoning, a "confession of love " is a singular event, whereas a "profession of love " should probably occur at regular intervals, no?

Comment: At random intervals, perhaps. At regular intervals is too much like rotating the tires.

Comment: That, unfortunately, is the price of bliss.  :-)

Comment: Bliss is overrated.

Answer (score 2):

I have nothing on hand to back this up. But my personal usage of these two phrases is the following:

A love confession is a confession of one's love to someone who prior to the confession did not already know he or she is loved by the speaker. In contrast, a confession of love is given to one's current lover to whom the confession does not come as new information.

For example, a person would make a "love confession" to his best friend's wife. However, the same person would make a "confession of his love" to his own wife on Valentine's Day.

Answer (score 1):

The misuse of (and legitimate need to correct) “assisted to” aside, the repetition of “to” in the Student’s original answer (assisted TO + confession TO) contributes heavily to my perception that it is somehow "wrong" or at least awkward.
Your decision to replace “assisted to” with “listened to” did nothing to resolve this “too many TOs” issue and tempted me at first to conclude that “love confession” must be the culprit.

It’s interesting to note that when asking if the Student’s use of “love confession” should have been maintained, you (intentionally?) "resolve" this issue by replacing “love confession **TO** Anna” with “3) … she listened to David’s love confession **FOR** Anna,” which is not what the Student wrote at all, and which, as Little Eva notes in an astute comment, does “sound wrong.”
Regardless of how it sounds, however, “love confession FOR Anna” is, again, not what the Student wrote and is therefore not the phrase at issue.

In order to fairly evaluate the Student’s actual use of “love confession **TO** Anna” on its own, without the awkwardness caused by “one too many TOs,” I feel that “assisted to” should be replaced by something other than “listened to.”
Any synonym not requiring “to” would work to provide this fair evaluation of the Student’s choice of words, and I notice that you suggested “witnessed” in a comment above, which is fine:

“ … she witnessed David’s love confession to Anna.”

Personally, I would use "heard" as my verb choice to conduct this fair evaluation for I believe it more closely describes the action of hearing a confession than "witnessed" does.  Regardless, with “heard,” "witnessed," or any suitable synonym not requiring "to" in place of “assisted to/listened to” the Student’s answer gets the opportunity it deserves to be fairly evaluated and in my opinion, loses much, if not all, of its awkwardness:

> … she heard David’s love confession to Anna.

(Now if it’s true, as you mentioned in response to Little Eva’s good answer, that “… you do not say: "**My/your/his** etc. love confession **to**," then, of course, the issue is resolved; but then again, if it is so clear that “… [one does] not say: "**My/your/his** etc. love confession **to**," why was this ever deemed to be an issue in the first place?)

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree, "overheard" is not correct. in the American short story Sabina is present at the restaurant table while her boyfriend declares his love for Anna. "Overheard" suggests that hearing the news was either accidental, or that the speaker (the confessor) was unaware of Sabina listening. The issue is I can't explain *why* "love confession" sounds wrong. I was asking for an explanation.

Comment: Either *heard* or *listened* will do. My question doesn't ask about this.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Is the expression 'She listened to David's love confession'  more problematical for you than 'She listened to David's love confession for Anna'?  Is it the modification of 'love'  by 'for Anna', that jars when the noun adjunct form is used?

Comment: @RKING I don't know how to make my question clearer than it is. If you feel that omitting (my addition)  "for" makes the sentence sound more idiomatic, then could you explain "why"? Moreover, I don't see this difference between "to" and "for" where the verb *confess* is involved. I confess something *to* a person. I confess my love *for* a person. Both prepositions can be used.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion over the essential meaning of nouns 'in apposition' in English. So-called 'apposition' in English is general, not relating to a specific example, so a 'love confession' is not wrong; but it means 'a confession relating to love' while 'confession of love' means 'a confession about a specific love' - in this case, obviously his.

Indeed, his 'love confession' could equally well be a confession that he does not reciprocate her love; his 'confession of love' could not carry that meaning.

Comment: *'love confession' could equally well be a confession that he does not reciprocate her love; his 'confession of love' could not carry that meaning*. That's an interesting interpretation of two phrases that, IMO, carry the same semantic value. If you can support your assertion with linked references, I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am not duplicating anything said above (I don't think so, but them is a lot of words).  For me, the two versions are different primarily because one uses a common word order and the other does not.

A ***love confession*** does not sound special or important.  The quotidian formulation suggests that there are many kinds of confession and this one happens to be (an ordinary, banal) one (of many) relating to love. ("Whose love confession shall we hear tonight")

A ***confession of love*** has a formality of structure that suggests the love is especially significant.

Consider how these two versions sound

*She understood the flower he gave her to be a confession of love*

*She understood the flower he gave her to be a love confession* (and not, say, a guilt confession)

Comment: Yes indeed @PapaPoule!  I've altered, to level the playing field.  I do agree with you tho', there's not a lot in it.

Answer (score 0):

We are in the territory of style and creative way of expressing ourselves. I don't see any substantial grammatical or syntactic violation in either of the two parts of the question.

1) "love confession"

It is somewhat understood, but not standard, and not commonly used. I checked a 450-million-word American English corpus there is none. (COCA)

2) "Confession of love" is common, used and standard; however, if this to have a more subtle nuances "to encourage David to confess his love for Anna..." because the writer seems to place some premium on another person's role to induce David to spill the beans.

Oh, "love confession" is not an idiomatic phrase in English.

Answer (score 0):

My  vote goes to "one's confession of love".

The reason is simply that a noun cannot qualify another noun directly , so to signify the possession of former over latter, one must use either apostrophe or 'of'. 
In the phrase **One's love confession** 'love' and 'confession' are inappropriately connected. Further since both 'love' and 'Confession' are non-living nouns the possession of former over latter should be denoted using 'of'.

Thus in my opinion **one's confession of love** correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just my take. At Google Books:

1. ["confessed his love"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22confessed%20his%20love&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22confessed%20his%20love%22)

About 81,200 results

2. ["confession of love"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22confessed%20his%20love&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22confession%20of%20love%22)

About 18,300 results

3. ["love confession"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22confessed%20his%20love&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22love%20confession%22)

About 3,950 results

This to me shows clearly that you have to make every effort to use 1, as it seems that in this particular case the native speakers are simply much more comfortable with the action than with the noun phrases referring to it :-)

This also tells us that your choice 1) is much better than the other two.

Now that we have "confessed his love" as a clear part of the target sentence, how about the rest?

"assisted"? No, this is too intellectual — as cold as a fish. It's also, I would guess, not Old Saxon, but imported with the Normans, thus not affecting the native guts as sharply. Use it when you write something formal, analytical, perhaps in managerial jargon, but not when you want to be emotional.

"listened"? Better, but not good enough, as it doesn't reflect her visual experience. She might do that even from behind a door (shame on her).

"watched" would be better in that respect, and this is confirmed:

"she listened as he"

About 19,600 results

"she watched as he"

About 167,000 results

Thus, I'd suggest

*She watched as David confessed his love to Anna.*

or

*She watched **/transfixed/mesmerized/in shock/** as David confessed his love to Anna.*

the latter to better reflect her own emotional state/experience.

Or, to give some weight to her state, let's do some fronting:

***/Transfixed/Mesmerized/In shock/***, she watched as David confessed his love to Anna.

or:

***/Transfixed/Mesmerized/In shock/***, she watched David confess**ing** his love to Anna.

In a romance novel, you might even say:

*She **beheld** as David confessed his love to Anna.*

> [The Ladies' museum. New and improved](https://books.google.ca/books?id=8mwEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA6&dq=%22she%20beheld%20as%20he%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RbkSVa7JGIK-ggSI-YGACg&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22she%20beheld%20as%20he%22&f=false) - Page 6 1832
>
> With indescribable horror she beheld, as he raised his visor, the
>   unforgotten features of the Bathenien Ilderim.

:-))

Cheers.