# Word that means "love confession"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example sentence:

> Marcos was the guy who had recently joined Mary's company. Also the
>   guy who had recently **confessed** to her.

Is it clear what **confessed** mean in this context? Or maybe there's a word that means *love confession*?

Comment: related: [One’s love confession vs. One’s confession of love](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233648/one-s-love-confession-vs-one-s-confession-of-love)

Comment: There is no "*love confession*" in the text you quote. It's not at all clear from that text what kind of confession is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the meaning of your sentence, but others may not. So to make it clearer, add "his love" after "confessed":

> Marcos was the guy who had recently joined Mary's company. Also the guy who had recently **confessed his love** to her.

There are many examples for "confessed his love to her" on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22confessed%20his%20love%20to%20her%22).

Also, see the [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=confessed%20*%20love%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cconfessed%20%2A%20love%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bconfessed%20her%20love%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconfessed%20his%20love%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconfessed%20their%20love%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconfessed%20my%20love%20to%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I thought *confessed to her* was the common way of saying it.