# Word for "confess love" (to someone)

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that means that? I checked on [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/confess) but didn't find anything.

Example sentence:

> "By the way, I love you." That was how Ayumi __. Funnily enough, that
>   day I also confessed my love to someone.

Comment: capitulated? (Hip, hip hooray for Esperanto! - to meet the minimum character-count requirement)

Comment: ' Came out  ' - ?

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate, I don't think): [One’s love confession vs. One’s confession of love](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233648/one-s-love-confession-vs-one-s-confession-of-love)

Comment: 'Profess' rather than 'confess' was once traditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a single word, but you could certainly say *opened her heart*, or *shared/revealed her love/feelings*.